# geolocation continuely returning 'POSITION_UNAVAILABLE' in wearable app

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

I've been trying to get a simple web app displaying geo coordinates and speed however I am receiving a 'POSITION_UNAVAILABLE' error every time.

I've put the following permissions in the config.xml file;

```
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/feedback.vibration"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/location"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/power"/>
<tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
<tizen:setting hwkey-event="enable"/>
<tizen:setting background-support="enable"/>
```

And in the HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
<title>List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="speedPage">
    <header>
        <h2 class="ui-title">Boat speed</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="ui-content">
    <li><p id="speedOutput"></p></li>
    <li><p id="latitude"></p></li>
    <li><p id="longitude"></p></li
    <script>

        var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 50000, maximumAge: 5000};

        function success(position) {
        currentGpsPosLat = position.coords.latitude;
        currentGpsPosLong = position.coords.longitude;
        currentGPSPosLong = position.coords.speed;
        document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = currentGpsPosLat;
        document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = currentGpsPosLong;         
        }

        function error(error) {
        document.getElementById("speedOutput").innerHTML = error;
        document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = error.code;
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);


    </script>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

The output I am getting is

[object PositionError]
2

I've looked up the error code and it is POSITION_UNAVAILABLE. I've also tried

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

however I am still getting the same results.

I've verified that the watch is getting location signal by using Here WeGo and a Speedometer app at the same time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try after connecting with phone using Samsung Wearable app

Comment: Thanks Iqbal, this wasn't a factor as I'm using a watch with its own GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of device do you use, but it seems to me as the issue with privilege restriction existing since Tizen 4.0 - https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/security/privacy-related-permissions

'location' is privacy related, so it needs the additional explicit agreement from the user. You can do this using Web API PPM module - https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/5.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/ppm.html

Check current state of user's permission:

```
> tizen.ppm.checkPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/location")
< "PPM_ASK"
```

PPM_ASK says that you properly gave the permission in config.xml, but also need to request it directly from user.

```
> tizen.ppm.requestPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/location", (s) => {console.log("success")}, (e) => {console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(e))})
```

On watch, the pop-up will be shown. User can give the permission then.
The result of checking should be as follow:

```
> tizen.ppm.checkPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/location")
< "PPM_ALLOW"
```

Your location-related code should work then (if your device does not have GPS module, you need to pair watch with mobile to have the location properly gathered).

Comment: Thanks for this. It's now successfully asking for permissions on my single page test however when the app launches I am still getting the same results.If I run tizen.ppm.checkPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/location") after this I get "PPM_ASK" again. It's like it's not actually saving it to the log. Sorry, this is my first foray into something more than the most simple app and finding the Tizen documentation difficult to comprehend.

Comment: tizen.ppm.checkPermission and tizen.ppm.requestPermission methods need to be executed in each application you want to access location. The basic scenario of your app, should be in some init function:
1. check the privacy-related privileges status
2. if it is not "PPM_ALLOW", then exectue tizen.ppm.requestPermission() to ask user via pop-up.
3. then you can use the code related to location normally.

Comment: Thank you again. I had the permission request as a script but once I moved it to the app.js file it worked perfectly. Thank you I've been stuck for a the last fortnight!